# Rails + AngularJS + Prerender.io (local server) setup not rendering pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, phantomjs, single-page-application, prerender

I am trying to setup [Prerender.io](http://prerender.io) server locally. I am Rails + AngularJs app.

Already pulled prerender repo and started the server with node.

```
$ export PORT=3001
$ node server.js
2015-03-13T08:15:48.152Z starting worker thread #0
2015-03-13T08:15:48.159Z starting worker thread #1
2015-03-13T08:15:48.161Z starting worker thread #2
2015-03-13T08:15:48.163Z starting worker thread #3
2015-03-13T08:15:48.506Z starting phantom on port [12301]
2015-03-13T08:15:48.523Z Server running on port 3001
2015-03-13T08:15:48.524Z starting phantom on port [12304]
2015-03-13T08:15:48.526Z starting phantom on port [12303]
2015-03-13T08:15:48.530Z starting phantom on port [12302]
2015-03-13T08:15:48.541Z Server running on port 3001
2015-03-13T08:15:48.548Z Server running on port 3001
2015-03-13T08:15:48.558Z Server running on port 3001
2015-03-13T08:15:51.750Z started phantom
2015-03-13T08:15:51.755Z started phantom
2015-03-13T08:15:51.757Z started phantom
2015-03-13T08:15:51.758Z started phantom
2015-03-13T08:15:56.715Z getting
```

If I hit below URL , I am getting page rendered properly .

```
localhost:3001/http://localhost:3000/register
```

But when using [Rails Prerender middleware](https://github.com/prerender/prerender_rails) , Page is not rendering and its show empty page. I am hitting below URL.

```
http://localhost:3000/register?_escaped_fragment_=
```

It seems , its correctly hitting server and response with status 200 , but page is not displayed.

[image]

Output with escape fragment

[image]

Any help will be much appreciable. I can provide more details if need.

**USING PUMA SERVER**

[image]

**Response from Prerender.io**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Thin webserver? You should make sure you're using a multi process server like Puma or Unicorn since the Rails blocks I/O waiting for the Prerender response.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick answer. I am using PUMA server , but its not working still. I attached more screenshots for your reference. Let me know if you need any code to be pasted . You help will be useful.

Comment: How many processes were you running? Could you try cranking it up by a lot just to see if it works? Also, there's two entries in the Prerender console meaning there were 2 separate requests. Did you try the page two separate times or did the middleware actually send two requests somehow?

Comment: It solved when deploying to Apache + Passenger , so as your said initially the solution is  "Multi process" . Thanks for the help.